# Can I reinstall Starcraft 2 on Windows using the key from my Mac?

Tags: starcraft-2, macos

I want to buy StarCraft 2, but have one question.

Currently I have an iMac and I know I can install SC2 on it.

My problem is that later I want to sell this Mac and buy a PC.

Will I be able to install it on my future Windows box and run it with the same key without paying additionally? (I will not be using the Mac anymore).

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thing. The people on the forums are complaining to the poor perfomance of the game on Mac even on a i5 or better. On the other hand, Mag Roader gave you the best answer :P

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is yes, you will be able to install Starcraft II on any future box you have.

Soon after you purchase Starcraft II, you will link your key to your [battle.net](http://battle.net/) account. If you don't have a battle.net account yet, you will have to create one. You must link your key to play the game.

Once your account is linked, you never need your key again. What's more, you don't even need the install disc again, as you can download the entire game client off the battle.net site. The disc itself is just a convenient way to install the game; I myself bought it and didn't even use it. The same is now true for any PC Blizzard game released in the past 12 years, including Diablo 2 and the original Starcraft.

What's more, for Starcraft II your match history, achievements, and current campaign progress will also transfer because it's stored on the server. There may be some stuff like Replays which won't transfer over to your new box, but for the most part you will be playing the game where you left off.

The only way you could hose yourself here is by somehow losing access to your battle.net account, for example by forgetting your password or permanently losing your internet connection. I'd recommend against that.

Comment: Great answer.  If I could upvote it twice, I would.

Comment: +1 for you.  Does this mean that I can install starcraft II natively on both windows and mac simultaneously (using boot camp) so that I can play quickly with the performance issues on the mac, but if I have time, switch to bootcamp for better performance?

Comment: @Mechko I can't think of a reason why you couldn't do this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will be able to re-install it on Windows later. The DVD in the box contains both the Mac and Windows versions of the game. It also ties Starcraft 2 to your Battle.net account, allowing you to also download the client too.

One other thing to mention is that your campaign progress and versus stats are also tied to your Battle.net account, so when you switch computers you won't lose everything that you've already done in the game.

Answer (score -3):

I would check the package contents for the item you're ordering.  Typically manufacturers will include a CD/DVD for each OS capable of running the software.  Unfortunately though, that isn't always the case.  If the vendor only includes one order link for the game then it's probably safe to assume it includes both OS disks.

Comment: Yeah, except Blizzard hasn't shipped the Mac and PC versions of their games separately since like WarCraft II. Over a decade ago. The company is famous among Mac gamers for this. Not to mention that Blizzard specifically addressed this question in the StarCraft II FAQ.